# Asking patches with pycor = range to sprout turtles

Tags: netlogo

one. i am trying to setup a supply-chain structure in netlogo. elements of each layer (i.e DistributionCenters) have the same xcor and i want them to be evenly spaced on ycor ( note that the number of DistrubutionCenters is variable and is imported using a slider). i have tried many ways and came to the following idea but the patches do not sprout the turtles

---

```
breed [Producers Producer]
breed [DistributionCenters DistributionCenter]

to setup

  clear-all

  set-default-shape DistributionCenters "house ranch"
  let DCR1 (- floor ( n_DistributionCenters / 2 ))
  let DCR2 (  floor ( n_DistributionCenters / 2 ))
  let DistRange (range DCR1 DCR2 1)
  ask patches with [ pxcor = 0 and pycor = DistRange][sprout-DistributionCenters 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are asking whether a number (`pycor`) equals a list. These are different types of data. So, your example is equivalent to this complete model (with the list printed out):

```
to testme
  clear-all
  let selected (range 0 15 3)
  print selected
  ask patches with [pxcor = 0 and pycor = selected] [set pcolor blue]
end
```

One way is to iterate through the list using `foreach` and `ask` the appropriate patch individually:

```
to testme2
  clear-all
  let selected (range 0 15 3)
  print selected
  foreach selected
  [ here -> ask patch 0 here [set pcolor blue]
  ]
end
```

Alternatively, I think this is conceptually similar to what you were trying to do - it uses `member?` to test membership of a list:

```
to testme3
  clear-all
  let selected (range 0 15 3)
  print selected
  ask patches with [pxcor = 0 and member? pycor selected] [set pcolor blue]
end
```